# If input is checked, apply class to <body>, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, class, input

I have a very newbie question. I have this 'hamburger' menu: http://alexe.ro/beta/ (top right), and if it's checked, I would like to add a class to the `<body>`, if it's possible.

The catch is that I would like to use just javaScript, and not jQuery.
It would help my (severely limited) javaScript knowledge if I knew how to do this.

This is the code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="menuToggle" id="menu-toggle-right" data-toggle="right">
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With the current question we cannot do anything and downvotes will be coming any second now. Post the code that controls the opening and closing of the menu so we can help you to hook up some code to that, that adds/removes a class to the body.

Comment: Updated, thank you and sorry. It's just an input button, the rest is done through CSS.

Comment: Do you need to attach a pre-existing class to the BODY tag, or create a whole new class and apply it to the BODY?

Comment: DavidP, the latter. The answer below, by wlin, answers 99% of my initial question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setAttribute.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('body'); 
  a[0].setAttribute("class", "red");
}
```

```css
.red {
background:red;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ctrl" onChange="myfunction();">
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but there is just one more small thing. How can I get it to toggle? When unchecking the input, it should remove the class.

Thank you, immensely.

Comment: use a if( ) statement to check if the input is check.  why don't you try it, if you run into problem let me know.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: Ended up modifying your genius script a little bit, and ended up with this:

'function myfunction() {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('red');
}'

Thank you!

Comment: that is fine, just note that querySelector is i.e. 8+. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Answer (score 1):

Detect if it have been checked inside the event handler for `onchange` on your checkbox.

Inside that checkbox you check the `checked` property to see if it have been checked or not and then use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add or remove you desired class.

```js
document.getElementById('menu-toggle-right').onchange = function() {
    var method = this.checked ? 'add' : 'remove';
    document.body.classList[method]('my-class');
}
```

```css
body.my-class { background-color:#f44; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="menuToggle" id="menu-toggle-right" data-toggle="right">
```